# Jquery button to reset checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried using checkbox rather than buttons it works fine but I wanted to try replacing it with a button. I can't make it work, when I click the button it does check the checkbox that I want but when I try to click it again it won't uncheck. I tried making another button it's not working, the purpose of the second button is to reset the checked boxes and check that box that it requires. Can somebody help me?

```js
$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:not(:checked), input:checkbox.name:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:checked, input:checkbox.name:checked").click();
  }
});

$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.name:not(:checked), input:checkbox.age:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.name:checked, input:checkbox.age:checked").click();
  }
});

$("input").change(function() {
  _tot = $("input").length
  _tot_checked = $("input").length;
  if (_tot != _tot_checked) {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
    $("#chkjob").prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$(function() {

  var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox");
  var $tbl = $("#basic_table");

  $chk.prop('checked', false);

  $chk.click(function() {
    var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).prop("name"));
    $(colToHide).toggle();
  });
});

$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="checkAll" value="List by EmployeeID and Name" />
<input type="button" id="chkjob" value="List by Name and Age " />


<div id="grpChkBox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="empid" class="empid" /> Employee ID</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="name" class="name" /> Name</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="age" class="age" /> Age</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="birth" class="birth" /> Birthdate</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="los" class="los" /> Length of Service</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="jobtitle" class="jobtitle" /> Job Title</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="actions" class="actions" /> actions taken</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="tab" class="tab" /> Tax and Benefits</p>
</div>
<table class="table" id="basic_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col" class="empid">id</th>
      <th scope="col" class="name">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="age">Age</th>
      <th scope="col" class="birth">Birthdate</th>
      <th scope="col" class="los">Length of Service</th>
      <th scope="col" class="jobtitle">Job title</th>
      <th scope="col" class="actions">actions taken</th>
      <th scope="col" class="tab">tax</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="empid">{{$report->id}}</th>
      <td class="name">{{$report->name}}</td>
      <td class="age">{{$report->age}}</td>
      <td class="birth">{{$report->birthdate}}</td>
      <td class="los">{{$report->length_of_service}}</td>
      <td class="jobtitle">{{$report->job_title}}</td>
      <td class="actions">{{$report->actions}}</td>
      <td class="tab">{{$report->tax}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Where are you changing the checkAll button so that the truth of `$(this).prop("click")` toggles between true and false?

Comment: You modify the `checked` prop but you test against the `click` prop.

Comment: `_tot_checked` and `_tot` in the input change handler are being set to the same selector value as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply toggle the checkboxes using the `.prop()` and select all of them once rather than binding 2 different click events see below

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectables = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='empid'],input[type='checkbox'][name='name'],input[type='checkbox'][name='age']");
  selectables.prop("checked", !selectables.prop("checked"));
});
```

or you can alternatively call

```
selectables.trigger('click');
```

instead of

```
selectables.prop("checked", !selectables.prop("checked"));
```

so that your table columns also interact when selecting the button

then your this code block is what I would say **¯\_(ツ)_/¯** the statement `_tot != _tot_checked` will always evaluate to `false` as both of them will always have `10` and will always be equal you can remove it I should say

```
$("input").change(function() {
  _tot = $("input").length
  _tot_checked = $("input").length;

  if (_tot != _tot_checked) {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
    $("#chkjob").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

See below demo

```js
$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectables = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='empid'],input[type='checkbox'][name='name'],input[type='checkbox'][name='age']");
  selectables.trigger('click');
});


$(function() {

  var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input[type='checkbox']");
  var $tbl = $("#basic_table");

  $chk.prop('checked', false);

  $chk.on('click', function() {
    // console.log('click',$tbl.find("." + $(this).prop("name")).length);
    var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).prop("name"));
    $(colToHide).toggle();
  });
});

$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="checkAll" value="List by EmployeeID and Name" />
<input type="button" id="chkjob" value="List by Name and Age " />


<div id="grpChkBox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="empid" class="empid" /> Employee ID</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="name" class="name" /> Name</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="age" class="age" /> Age</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="birth" class="birth" /> Birthdate</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="los" class="los" /> Length of Service</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="jobtitle" class="jobtitle" /> Job Title</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="actions" class="actions" /> actions taken</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="tab" class="tab" /> Tax and Benefits</p>
</div>
<table class="table" id="basic_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col" class="empid">id</th>
      <th scope="col" class="name">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="age">Age</th>
      <th scope="col" class="birth">Birthdate</th>
      <th scope="col" class="los">Length of Service</th>
      <th scope="col" class="jobtitle">Job title</th>
      <th scope="col" class="actions">actions taken</th>
      <th scope="col" class="tab">tax</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="empid">{{$report->id}}</th>
      <td class="name">{{$report->name}}</td>
      <td class="age">{{$report->age}}</td>
      <td class="birth">{{$report->birthdate}}</td>
      <td class="los">{{$report->length_of_service}}</td>
      <td class="jobtitle">{{$report->job_title}}</td>
      <td class="actions">{{$report->actions}}</td>
      <td class="tab">{{$report->tax}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried making the second button work, but it's not going so well, how can I make it reset the checked boxes and checks the needed checkboxes?

Comment: which checkboxes does the second button needs to make checked ? @RayD

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/917czwz1/ here's the sample when I click the 2nd it unchecks the name and age, so I was thinking if it was better when I click the second button I would reset the checked checkboxes and check the boxes that are needed.

Comment: @RayD you can see [**`HERE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/917czwz1/1/) i have revised the script and separated the `toggleColumn()` function and reverted to use the first option that i suggested an removed `.trigger('click')` and added a reset part for both of the button selections.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to `uncheck` the boxes and then check them again.  Starting your `click` functions with the following code will uncheck the checkboxes before you proceed.  Note that I also changed your `dom ready` function to handle the `change` event instead of the `click` event.

```
$("#grpChkBox input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked", false);
```

```js
$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  $("#grpChkBox input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked", false);
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:not(:checked), input:checkbox.name:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:checked, input:checkbox.name:checked").click();
  }
});

$("#chkjob").on("click", function() {
  $("#grpChkBox input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked", false);
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.name:not(:checked), input:checkbox.age:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.name:checked, input:checkbox.age:checked").click();
  }
});


$(function() {
  var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox");
  var $tbl = $("#basic_table");
  $chk.change(function() {
    var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).prop("name"));
    $(colToHide).toggle();
  });
});

$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="checkAll" value="List by EmployeeID and Name" />
<input type="button" id="chkjob" value="List by Name and Age " />


<div id="grpChkBox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="empid" class="empid" /> Employee ID</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="name" class="name" /> Name</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="age" class="age" /> Age</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="birth" class="birth" /> Birthdate</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="los" class="los" /> Length of Service</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="jobtitle" class="jobtitle" /> Job Title</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="actions" class="actions" /> actions taken</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="tab" class="tab" /> Tax and Benefits</p>
</div>
<table class="table" id="basic_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col" class="empid">id</th>
      <th scope="col" class="name">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="age">Age</th>
      <th scope="col" class="birth">Birthdate</th>
      <th scope="col" class="los">Length of Service</th>
      <th scope="col" class="jobtitle">Job title</th>
      <th scope="col" class="actions">actions taken</th>
      <th scope="col" class="tab">tax</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="empid">{{$report->id}}</th>
      <td class="name">{{$report->name}}</td>
      <td class="age">{{$report->age}}</td>
      <td class="birth">{{$report->birthdate}}</td>
      <td class="los">{{$report->length_of_service}}</td>
      <td class="jobtitle">{{$report->job_title}}</td>
      <td class="actions">{{$report->actions}}</td>
      <td class="tab">{{$report->tax}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:not(:checked), input:checkbox.name:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.empid:checked, input:checkbox.name:checked").click();
  }
});

$("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("click")) {
    $("input:checkbox.name:not(:checked), input:checkbox.age:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox.name:checked, input:checkbox.age:checked").click();
  }
});

$("input").change(function() {
  _tot = $("input").length
  _tot_checked = $("input").length;
  if (_tot != _tot_checked) {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
    $("#chkjob").prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$(function() {

  var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox");
  var $tbl = $("#basic_table");

  $chk.prop('checked', false);

  $chk.click(function() {
    var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).prop("name"));
    $(colToHide).toggle();
  });
});

$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="checkAll" value="List by EmployeeID and Name" />
<input type="button" id="chkjob" value="List by Name and Age " />


<div id="grpChkBox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="empid" class="empid" /> Employee ID</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="name" class="name" /> Name</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="age" class="age" /> Age</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="birth" class="birth" /> Birthdate</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="los" class="los" /> Length of Service</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="jobtitle" class="jobtitle" /> Job Title</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="actions" class="actions" /> actions taken</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="tab" class="tab" /> Tax and Benefits</p>
</div>
<table class="table" id="basic_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col" class="empid">id</th>
      <th scope="col" class="name">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="age">Age</th>
      <th scope="col" class="birth">Birthdate</th>
      <th scope="col" class="los">Length of Service</th>
      <th scope="col" class="jobtitle">Job title</th>
      <th scope="col" class="actions">actions taken</th>
      <th scope="col" class="tab">tax</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="empid">{{$report->id}}</th>
      <td class="name">{{$report->name}}</td>
      <td class="age">{{$report->age}}</td>
      <td class="birth">{{$report->birthdate}}</td>
      <td class="los">{{$report->length_of_service}}</td>
      <td class="jobtitle">{{$report->job_title}}</td>
      <td class="actions">{{$report->actions}}</td>
      <td class="tab">{{$report->tax}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```